# calendar View in android 3.0

Tags: android, calendar

I am trying to bring in the default Calendar's view into my app and i found its possible using this

```
 CalendarView calander = new CalendarView(this);
        setContentView(calander);
```

This shows the calendar in month mode. Is it possible to make the `CalendarView` show the calendar in hourly mode?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to write a custom implementation for that?